# Keys.RETURN doesn't work on this site using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate the purchase of an item on this website. When I first wrote the code for this, everything used to work smoothly, but I reran it again and the "Keys.RETURN" part stopped working.

1. Click on the search button to open the search bar
2. click inside the search bar so I can type my keys of interest.

   ```
   # click search bar button 
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='site-nav__link search-wrap']/span[1]").click()
   #click actual search bar (to type keys) 
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='input-group search-bar search-bar\--header serch-box']/input[1]").click()
   ```
3. The second step types out my keys of interest, which also works fine.

   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='input-group search-bar search-bar\--header serch-box']/input[1]").send_keys('yo')`
4. Click enter after the keys have been typed so it actually searches for the item

   Attempt 1 = `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='input-group search-bar search-bar\
   --header serch-box']/input[1]").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

   Attempt 2 = `driver.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

   Attempt 3 = Inserting implicit waits after entering keys.

None of these have worked for me, the funny part is this use to work fine yesterday but now that I am trying it today it isn't working. Once the keys are typed the search bar automatically just closes... Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies for the long post ! :)

Comment: Could you please format your code?  Place the code portions in backticks `\`\``

Comment: My bad. Just fixed it

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='input-group search-bar search-bar--header serch-box']").submit()`

Comment: Hasn't worked unfortunately.

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "Once the keys are typed the search bar automatically just closes..."? Did that always happen or just since the problem started?

Comment: since the problem started. What I mean is that once it inputs 'yo' into the search bar, it inputs it and then the search bar just goes away ( as if it wasn't clicked). Hope that makes sense.